# Stuttering orbit animation when updating css through javascript over small interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make some DOM element rotate smoothly around a fixed point. I'm writing this from scratch using jQuery and no matter what update speed I choose for the setInterval or how small I go with the amount of degrees the orbit advances on each loop, I get this janky staircase animation effect. I've tried using jquery's .animate instead of the .css hoping it would smooth things out but I cant seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

In other words, it's not as smooth as rotating an image in HTML5 canvas. I want to make it smoother.

[Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/4rLF5/1/)

Notice how the animation is not quite smooth?

For reference, here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<button class="stop">STOP</button>
<button class="start">START</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#div{
    position:absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.dot{
    position:absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
}
button{
    position:absolute;
}

.stop{
    top:200px;
}
.start{
    top:225px;
}
```

**THE ALL IMPORTANT JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').data('angle', 90);
    var interval;

    $('.stop').on('click', function(){
        if(interval){
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });

    $('.start').on('click', function(){
        if(!interval){
            interval = setBoxInterval();
        }
    });

    interval = setBoxInterval();
});

function drawOrbitingBox(degrees){
    var centerX = 100,
        centerY = 100,
        div = $('#div'),
        orbitRadius = 50;

    //dot might not be perfectly centered
    $('.dot').css({left:centerX, top:centerY});

    //given degrees (in degrees, not radians), return the next x and y coords
    function coords(degrees){
        return {left:centerX + (orbitRadius * Math.cos((degrees*Math.PI)/180)), 
                top :centerY - (orbitRadius * Math.sin((degrees*Math.PI)/180))};
    }

    //increment the angle of the object and return new coords through coords()
    function addDegrees(jqObj, degreeIncrement){
        var newAngle = jqObj.data('angle') + degreeIncrement;
        jqObj.data('angle', newAngle);
        return coords(newAngle);
    }

    //change the left and top css property to simulate movement
    //  I've tried changing this to .animate() and using the difference
    //  between current and last position to no avail
    div.css(addDegrees(div, degrees), 1);
}

function setBoxInterval(){
    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        drawOrbitingBox(-0.2); //This is the degree increment
    }, 10); //This is the amount of time it takes to increment position by the degree increment

    return interval;
}
```

I'd rather not resort to external libraries/plugins but I will if that's the accepted way of doing this kind of stuff. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Actually if you set interval to 1 it becomes quite smooth

Comment: Yeah but you can still see that twitchy "staircase" curving, and i'll be using this on bigger images in which that stuttering is far more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the value you set for *top* and *left* properties is rounded up. You should try using CSS Transforms.
Combining CSS Animations/Transitions and CSS Transforms you should also be able to get the animation without JavaScript.

Comment: I'll look into it and get back to you!

Comment: Try changing line 32 into
`return {transform: "translate("+(centerX + (orbitRadius * Math.cos((degrees*Math.PI)/180)))+"px,"+(centerY - (orbitRadius * Math.sin((degrees*Math.PI)/180)))+"px)"};`

Comment: I don't know about you but I'm getting the same result. [See the updated jsFiddle with your suggested changes](http://jsfiddle.net/4rLF5/2/).

Comment: with Chromium/Chrome is fine, what browser are you using?

Comment: Hm you're right in chrome it looks great! I'm using FireFox 25.0.1, any idea why it's not as smooth?

Comment: Well, it seems that Gecko still rounds translation, but if you add another transform like a tiny rotation it works fine. Look at 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176#c8. Just tried with `return {transform: "translate("+(centerX + (orbitRadius * Math.cos((degrees*Math.PI)/180)))+"px,"+(centerY - (orbitRadius * Math.sin((degrees*Math.PI)/180)))+"px) rotate(0.001deg"};`, looks fine, although it's an horrible hack.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I run into that myself! 
There is actually nothing you can do, the stuttering you see is the pixel size. The pixel is the minimal step for css based animations, you can't do "half pixels" or "0.2 pixels". You will see that the same keeps happening with css3 animations.

The only solution is to speed up your animation, i'm afraid.

Also, cosndsider using rquestAnimationFrame instead of interval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame